# Replace buffer of a fopencookie: internal buffer on the first call?

Tags: c, glibc

I'm trying to create a file-like object using the `FILE` interface and
fopencookie.

My goal is to have a fixed size buffer, and to always have a prefix "HDR" in
the beginning of each printed line.

For instance, if the user code goes for

```
fprintf(fd, "hello there\n");
fprintf(fd, "how are you?\n");
fprintf(fd, "let's try again...\n");
```

I want to print

```
HDRhello there
HDRhow are you?
HDRlet's try again...
```

In order to accomplish this, I did a little prototype, which uses
fopencookie to provide a fixed-size buffer, shifted of as many character as
needed to store the header "HDR".

```
struct blah
{
    FILE* fd;
    char* buffer;
};

void blah_init(struct blah* blah, size_t len)
{
    blah->buffer = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    blah->buffer[len] = 0;
    int hdrlen = snprintf(blah->buffer, len + 1, "HDR");
    cookie_io_functions_t cbacks = {
        .write = mywrite,
        .close = myclose,
    };
    blah->fd = fopencookie(blah, "w", cbacks);
    setvbuf(blah->fd, blah->buffer + hdrlen, _IOFBF, len - hdrlen);
}
```

To see what happens when I print, I added dummy implementations of `mywrite`
and `myclose`.

```
ssize_t mywrite(void* cookie, const char* buf, size_t len)
{
    struct blah* blah = (struct blah*) cookie;

    fprintf(stderr, "contains: \"%s\" (%p)\n", buf, buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "actually: \"%s\" (%p)\n", blah->buffer, blah->buffer);
    return len;
}

int myclose(void* cookie)
{
    free(((struct blah*)cookie)->buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

So I expect `contans:` to be followed by the string printed by the user
code, and `actually:` to be followed by the same string, prefixed with the
header.

In other words, given this main:

```
int main()
{
    struct blah blah;
    blah_init(&blah, 20);

    fputs("goat chee", blah.fd);
    fputs("se or ", blah.fd);
    fflush(blah.fd);
    fputs("goat soup", blah.fd);
    fclose(blah.fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to see

```
contains: "goat chee" (x + 3)
actually: "HDRgoat chee" (x)
contains: "se or " (x + 3)
actually: "HDRse or " (x)
contains: "goat soup" (x + 3)
actually: "HDRgoat soup" (x)
```

While surprisingly I get…

```
contains: "goat chee" (0x400a40)
actually: "HDR" (0x51ef040)
contains: "se or " (0x51ef043)
actually: "HDRse or " (0x51ef040)
contains: "goat soup" (0x51ef043)
actually: "HDRgoat soup" (0x51ef040)
```

So, apparently the first call to my write function is cheating and using
some internal buffer, instead of the one I provided it with.

Is this the normal behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? glibc bug?

Here follows the complete code, should someone feel like trying.
I'm currently running this under Fedora 27, with glibc 2.26
(`glibc-2.26-27.fc27.x86_64`)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct blah
{
    FILE* fd;
    char* buffer;
};

ssize_t mywrite(void* cookie, const char* buf, size_t len)
{
    struct blah* blah = (struct blah*) cookie;

    fprintf(stderr, "contains: \"%s\" (%p)\n", buf, buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "actually: \"%s\" (%p)\n", blah->buffer, blah->buffer);
    return len;
}

int myclose(void* cookie)
{
    free(((struct blah*)cookie)->buffer);
    return 0;
}

void blah_init(struct blah* blah, size_t len)
{
    blah->buffer = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    blah->buffer[len] = 0;
    int hdrlen = snprintf(blah->buffer, len + 1, "HDR");
    cookie_io_functions_t cbacks = {
        .write = mywrite,
        .close = myclose,
    };
    blah->fd = fopencookie(blah, "w", cbacks);
    setvbuf(blah->fd, blah->buffer + hdrlen, _IOFBF, len - hdrlen);
}

int main()
{
    struct blah blah;
    blah_init(&blah, 20);

    fputs("goat chee", blah.fd);
    fputs("se or ", blah.fd);
    fflush(blah.fd);
    fputs("goat soup", blah.fd);
    fclose(blah.fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a bug in your problem statement? "I want to print" is not consistent with "prefix "HDR" in the beginning of each printed line."

Comment: @EmployedRussian The output I get is somewhat different from what I would expect, indeed. But I'm more interested in the fact that glibc won't actually use my buffer immediately, but only from the second call on.

Comment: I am not talking about the output you *get*. I am talking about the output you *expect* -- it doesn't match what you *say* you want.

Comment: @EmployedRussian yeah, it looked confusing, indeed. Fixed.